# Linux Ubuntu apache2 config

Tags: apache2-module

I have a question about the apache2 config on Linux.

can someone give me the content and location
for the apache2 config file in Ubuntu18.04?

I have problems, because the .htaccess files are not processed( routing and indexing).

Thank you for your time 
:-)

Comment: For the configuration try first checking the ubuntu (https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html) and apache documentation (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/). The first link shows the location of the different conf files (probably you are looking for /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf).
If there is something not working with the configuration try posting the relevant files and explaining what exactly is not working, the more details you add the easiest will be for others to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the location is: /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

And my content is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

   <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>


    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Don't forget to restart the service:

sudo a2ensite 000-default.conf

sudo systemctl restart apache2.service